# Calculate the surface area of different elements in a picture (micrograph)

Tags: image-processing

This is a micrograph of a hybrid material that contains glass fiber (small white dots), carbon fibers (big grey dots) and a matrix that contains everything! I would like to calculate the surface area (volume fraction) of each of the elements.

[image]

Comment: Standard references are [How to count cells](https://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) and [Analyze segmented cells in an image](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/AnalyzeSegmentedCellsInAnImage.html). They can be a good starting point, especially since it looks like `Binarize` should be pretty good at separating the different types of elements from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all quite crude and largely done by eye.

```
img =
```

[image]

```
totalMeasure = 
 ImageMeasurements[Binarize[1 - ImageSubtract[img, img]], "Total"]

(* Out[348]= 170240. *)
```

Get the glass part by playing with blurring and binarization.

```
imgGlass = 
 MorphologicalBinarize[
  Blur[MorphologicalBinarize[Blur[img, 1], .5], 2], .15]
ImageMeasurements[imgGlass, "Total"]
ImageMeasurements[imgGlass, "MeanIntensity"]
```

[image]

```
(* 49506.

0.290801 *)
```

Now subtract and binarize to get the carbon part.

```
imgCarbon = 
 Binarize[ImageSubtract[img, Blur[imgGlass, 4]], .18]
ImageMeasurements[imgCarbon, "Total"]
ImageMeasurements[imgCarbon, "MeanIntensity"]
```

[image]

```
(* Out[585]= 66975.

Out[586]= 0.393415 *)
```

To see if this is at all consistent, also get the matrix part.

```
imgBlack = Binarize[ColorNegate[img], .75]
ImageMeasurements[imgBlack, "Total"]
ImageMeasurements[imgBlack, "MeanIntensity"]
```

[image]

```
(* Out[709]= 55782.

Out[710]= 0.327667 *)
```

So it comes to around 100% but still this was all from using eyeballing to see if the pictures were in the right ballpark. I'd expect maybe up to 10% relative error in each of the measurements.